# Show that the metric space of smooth parametrized curves is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $a$ and $b$ be points in $ \mathbb R^2$ and let $X$ be the set of all smooth parametrized curves joining $a$ to $b$ in $\mathbb R^2$, with parameter interval $[0,1]$. That is, $X$ is the set of all continuously differentiable functions $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, with $\gamma(0)=a $ and $\gamma(1) = b$. Let
$\delta(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)$ = $sup\{||\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_2(t)||: t \in [0,1]\},$ then $\delta$ is a metric on $X$. Show that the metric space ($X; \delta$) is not complete.

I know that I'm supposed to find a sequence of functions that is Cauchy but doesn't converge. I have been trying to find such a sequence for half an hour but I couldn't come with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Pick your favorite non-differentiable continuous curve and approximate it with $C^1$ curves. Something like $t\mapsto (|t-1/2|,0)$ should work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: Suppose $\gamma_n$ is a family of $C^1$-curves which converges uniformly to the curve $t\mapsto (|t-1/2|,0)$. Then $\gamma_n$ is Cauchy on $C^1$. But it is not convergent. If if where, it would converge to a non-$C^1$ curve.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you!